# Mail stuck in queue folder using IIS 6.0 SMTP server

Tags: domain-name-system, iis-6, smtp

I have finished setting up my server but when I sent email it got stuck in queue folder. This was a test email which I put in pickup folder.

So I checked my log file. I have pasted the log files [here](http://pastebin.com/UcFUXun3). I have been looking for solution but none troubleshoots based on the logfile.